# Can't find where to change 'background-attachment: fixed;'

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Have been scratching my head for half a day trying to work this out (noob web designer with no real idea of what they are doing).

I am trying to change "background-attachment" (highlighted in picture) from fixed but cannot find where to locate it?

I can't seem to find it in the css files under div.page_header_wrap

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnqEw.jpg)

Comment: This looks like it's inline css hardcoded into your html code. It could also be added via javascript. So check your html and/or javascript files.

Comment: You can use `#content>div.page_header_wrap{background-attachment: initial !important}` and don't care where it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at an inline style. Inline styles can be overridden in CSS with the `!important` rule:

```css
.foo{
  padding:1em;
  color:white;
  background:green !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="foo" style="background:red">Foo</span>
```

Comment: You can try this `div.page_header_wrap {background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-attachment: fixed !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful plugin called 'string locator' which helped me find it. It was located in functions.php but not the one under 'theme functions' there was another functions.php in the theme files under 'theme creator name here'. Glad that is sorted, I have allot to learn, time for a break. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: If this class is added dynamically by PHP, you're probably better off just overriding it in CSS.